# ipatool failed with an exception: #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `ex'

Tags: ios, swift, archive, adhoc

When I go to archive version 2.1.4 of my project with build number 24, the project is successfully archived, but when I try to export it as `AdHoc !` I got the following error:

[image]

I tried a lot and googled but all questions were about `Ruby` and I'm working with `Swift` and `Xcode`.

ipatool failed with an exception:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method 'ex'